# Returning data in a sequence in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, counter

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8PIb.jpg)The situation: (please see attached image)
The operation sequence does not always start with the same number or proceed in a standard increment.  Because of this it cannot be used to return the correct information by sequence.  I used countif to determine the number of sequences per pn but i cannot come up with a formula or vba to do what i want.  I am using an index match formula to return the information from two other spreadsheets.  I feel like i should be able to incorporate a counter in the formula to look at the pull the information back in the correct sequence.
Unfortunately, my skills are not that developed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Phil

[image: Situation Description]
[[additional description of what i'm trying to do]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4nAt.jpg)

Comment: If you could provide an example of input and expected output, maybe it would be easier to understand exactly what you are trying to do. As it is, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Christofer, thanks for taking a look.  Hopefully I can clarify.  The input would be column 2 from the master spreadsheet.  This is the part number I am looking for.  The output would be all of the rows (related to the input part number) in columns 4-9 in sequential order (operation sequence).   Not sure if that helps.

Comment: The output is retrieved from a second spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still confused on exactly what we are trying to achieve, or rather how. You enter the part number in **1a** the master sheet, and you want **3b** to fill up with the data from **3a** by searching **1b**, using **2a** as a reference how many rows should be returned? Is that it? I'm not sure about the significance of the operation sequence. Do you need to order it somehow? You say that you are using a formula, but exactly what works and what doesn't with it? Also, you should probably share the formula, as that may shed some light on what we want to do.

Comment: 'I hope you can understand that I have to remove any company information from the formula in order to post but it doesn't change the structure.

'=INDEX(SOURCE SPREADSHEET'!$F$1:$F$20121,MATCH(PN FROM 1A IN MASTER SPREADSHEET,SOURCE SPREADSHEET'!$D$1:$D$20121,0)+(THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO INCREMENT THE ROW BY USING THE COUNTIF RESULT '2a'))  

By incrementing the row using the countif value I can index down to the appropriate row automatically instead of modifying the formula for each line.  I have 580 pn's and over 20k data lines to search through to find the correct operations.

Comment: your explanation is correct.  
I want the operations in the order they happen so that's why i'm not sure if i'm over thinking it and i should just be looking at the operation sequence as a numerical sorting tool.